# NamedQuery for most used tags

Tags: java, sql, jpa, jpql

Let's say I have the following 2 classes:

```
@Entity
class Article {

    @Id
    int id;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="articles")
    List<Tag> tags;
}

@Entity
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Tag.trends", query = "SELECT t FROM Tag t") // Some magic stuff here..
})
class Tag {

    @Id
    String name;

    @ManyToMany
    List<Articles> articles;
}
```

Now I want to create a named query to select the most used tags.

So this will require a *join*, *count* and an *order by*. But I can't seem to figure this out.

**Question:**
How can I select the most used tags?

For example, if the following articles have the following tags:

```
Article: Tags
0: A, B
1: A
2: C
3: A, C
```

**Output**

```
A // 3 times
C // 2 times
B // 1 time
```

Comment: you want to group all of the tags and get a count and order descending?

Comment: @Nicholas I'm not sure I want to group them. I want to order them descending by the number of occurrences in the article class instances.

Comment: there is presumably a join table in there somewhere, because an M-N without one would be a bit pointless

Comment: Btw: I understand you want unique tags in the tag table, but you should put a constraint and have an Integer or Long id in the tag table otherwise performance will be bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve what you want using something like

```
SELECT t FROM Tag t ORDER BY SIZE(t.articles) ASC
```

That would bring you the list of tags ordered by number of articles.

Comment: I'd use `desc` instead of `asc`, and `.setMaxResults()` to make the most popular tags appear first

Comment: @SashaSalauyou That's it. :)

Answer (score 1):

Work your way backwards on these kinds of problems. Start with the SQL query:

```
select 
  count(t.name), t.name 
from article a 
  join article_tags ats 
  join tag t 
where 
  a.id=ats.article_id 
  and ats.tag_id = t.id 
group by 
  t.name 
order by 
  count(t.name) 
desc;
```

Then the JPQL should more or less follow from that:

```
List<Tuple> t = em.createQuery("select t.name as name, count(t.name) as count from Article a join a.tags t group by (t.name) order by count(t.name) desc", Tuple.class).getResultList();
t.stream().forEach((tp)-> {
    System.out.println("Count of " + tp.get("name") + " = " + tp.get("count"));
});
```

This gives me the following output:

```
Hibernate: select tag2_.name as col_0_0_, count(tag2_.name) as col_1_0_ from Article article0_ inner join Tag_Article tags1_ on article0_.id=tags1_.articles_id inner join Tag tag2_ on tags1_.tags_id=tag2_.id group by tag2_.name order by count(tag2_.name) desc
Count of A = 2
Count of B = 1
Count of C = 1
```

UPDATE: If you want a list of tags, just change the first element of the tuple to be a tag. And of course you can ignore the count if you want:

```
List<Tag> t = em.createQuery("select t from Article a join a.tags t group by (t.name) order by count(t.name) desc", Tag.class).getResultList();
t.stream().forEach((tag)-> {
    System.out.println("Tag = " + tag.getName());
});
```

And get the following output:

```
Hibernate: select tag2_.id as id1_1_, tag2_.name as name2_1_ from Article article0_ inner join Tag_Article tags1_ on article0_.id=tags1_.articles_id inner join Tag tag2_ on tags1_.tags_id=tag2_.id group by tag2_.name order by count(tag2_.name) desc
Tag = A
Tag = B
Tag = C
```

Comment: Awesome, but how do I get the list of Tags from this efficiently?

Comment: But then I would need to query all tags by name, that would be inefficient.

Comment: Yes, my output is slightly confusing. I would like to retrieve a `List<Tag>`. I do not really care about the number of occurrences, it only has to be sorted by them. I don't want to sound unthankful, but I would like it to be more performant, I can't query all Tags again by name (Id). I hope you can alter it this way!

Comment: See updates for complete possibilities. You can select whatever you want.

Comment: why don't you just `from Tag t order by size(t.articles) desc` with `setMaxResults()`?

Comment: Mostly because I was assuming that getting the count was important, which I think it is.

Comment: @Nicholas, I'm sorry I was confusing. Thank you for your effort though!

Comment: You can still get the count from the article list after you retrieve the tags using something like tags.getArticles().size()